# geopandas with st.file_uploader produces fiona.DriverError

Tags: python, geopandas, streamlit

I am trying to upload and successively load a csv file containing LAT and LONG for further processing and display using streamlit.

CASE 1.
When reading the file with geopandas using the full file path I have no errors (also in streamlit). So this line works:

```
gpd.read_file(full_path_to_file)
```

CASE 2.
when I use the `st.file_uploader` with the same file `gpd.read_file` fails. This line fails:

```
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Load file", type=["csv"])
if uploaded_file is not None:
    gpd.read_file(uploaded_file, driver="CSV")
```

with this error:

```
self.session.start(self, **kwargs)
File "fiona/ogrext.pyx", line 588, in fiona.ogrext.Session.start
File "fiona/ogrext.pyx", line 143, in fiona.ogrext.gdal_open_vector
fiona.errors.DriverError: '/vsimem/441a78295d6047c9ae101296f9de2024' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

I don't understand what has changed between the two cases since the `gpd.read_file` is suppose to handle str, path object or file-like object. Any help?

Comment: As a general approach, I would read the CSV into a dataframe with pandas, and use `geopandas.points_from_xy` (https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.points_from_xy.html#geopandas.points_from_xy) to compute the geometries, and then pass both of those things to the GeoDataFrame constructor